# How can I a put a line like "==========" quickly in vim

Tags: vim

I am editing restructuredtext files.  I often need to put some charactors like "=-`~" in one line, and I want the length of the line match the previous line.  How should I do this in vim?

```
a long long title
=================
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `yyp:s/./=/g` ?

You can map that to a key, e.g.
`:map <F5> yyp:s/./=/g<CR>`

Comment: This is not the best answer, please see below for better solutions using visual mode to replace the pasted line rather than using a substitution.

Comment: What is bad about using a substitution exactly?

Comment: In this situation it is overkill, it requires the regular expression to be applied to every character on the line. It also changes your current search register so now you will be highlighting the **entire** document for no reason. It also wouldn't deal with any whitespace at the start of the line.

Comment: Oh yes. The highlighting is not that nice :D

Answer (score 17):

Another that will work:

```
yypv$r=
```

Comment: `yypVr=` is a bit shorter but the same technique.

Comment: @sidyll yy and Y are the same number of keystrokes :P.  Plus, many people `nnoremap Y y$` so Y is consistent with D and C.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `yypver=` to avoid searching & shift button as much as possible. This could of course also be mapped to a key.

Comment: Of course [Barry Brown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978462/how-can-i-a-put-a-line-like-quickly-in-vim/6978638#6978638) is correct, my test case of one word only was a bit too simple.

Comment: not meaning to troll, but did you mean `yypVr=`? To prevent confusion from future readers.

Comment: @sa125: actually I did not, but of course that's a valid solution *if the row does not end with `\s+`*

Comment: Won't the `e` go only as far as the end of the first word?

Answer (score 2):

If your line starts without any trailing whitespace:

```
Hello World
```

Normal Mode:

<kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

Gives:

```
Hello World
===========
```

Explanation

<kbd>Y</kbd> -> Yank entire line, like <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>
<kbd>p</kbd> -> paste the line
<kbd>V</kbd> -> select whole line in visual line mode
<kbd>r</kbd> -> replace all of select with next character
<kbd>=</kbd> -> the character to replace the others

If you line has leading whitespace, eg:

```
    Hello World
```

Use:

<kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

Giving:

```
    Hello World
    ===========
```

We use <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> visual selection to the end of the line, rather than using <kbd>V</kbd> to select everything on the line.

If you had trailing whitespace you can use the <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> movement to get to the last non whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

When the cursor is placed on `a long long line` you could use something like

```
:s/\(.*\)/\=submatch(1) . nr2char(13) . repeat('=', strlen(submatch(1)))/
```

In order to make it more easy to do the substitution, I'd then use a map:

```
nmap __ :s/\(.*\)/\=submatch(1) . nr2char(13) . repeat('=', strlen(submatch(1)))/
```

So, you can underline the line where the cursor is on with typing `__`.