# Is there a better way to create a line of some character in Vim?

Tags: vim, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I a put a line like “==========” quickly in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978462/how-can-i-a-put-a-line-like-quickly-in-vim)

### EDIT

Turns out this question is an exact duplicate of [How can I a put a line like "==========" quickly in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978462/344286) - but that one doesn't have such a great title...

---

When editing markdown style files, I like to have

```
Some heading
------------

Notice the line matches the length of the heading?
```

Currently I do:

```
yyp:s/./-/g
```

But I was wondering if there is any better (less keystrokes) way to do this?

Comment: As always in `vim` you can map the command. But, maybe you can convey the meaning of this operation with respect to your usecase, to find a more universal solution (i can't see why you want to substitute dots with a `-`)

Comment: @user1146332 I believe the `.` is regex that matches any single character on the line (and substitutes it with a `-`). The `/g` does it for the whole line (as opposed to just the first occurrence).

Comment: @Jeff Bridgman It's late and i didn't see the hint in the markup source, thanks for your comment. With this in mind i would make a markup specific mapping via an autocommand.

Comment: `yypv$r-` works and is slightly fewer keystrokes. I guess `yypVr-` is less characters, though you have to push shift to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've just discovered, you can do it in a few less key strokes:

`yypVr-` - 7, if you include the shift key.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have as a mapping.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Vim expert, but in any text editor creating and using macros helps me reduce keystrokes.

In normal mode, with the cursor placed on the line you want to underline, start recording a macro to buffer (a in this instance)

```
q a <enter>
```

Now, perform said commands.  In this case I've finished by inserting a new line after the series of '-' characters.  Before to leave insert mode before hitting q again to finish.

```
yyp:s/./-/gA<enter><esc>q
```

To underline any heading you might have, be in Normal mode with cursor on that line, and type:

```
@a<enter>
```

**Keystrokes**
Before: 18
After: 3
Savings of: ***15!***

AFAIK buffers can be assigned to 'a' through 'z'

Happy Vimming

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following code to my `~/.vimrc` for create just such headers. All I do is execute `ch=` on a line and it will create a line below filled with `=`'s. You could easily do `ch-` to create a header line of `-`'s as well.

```
"""" CreateHeaderLine
" Easily create heading mapping
" The following line is an example
" ================================
" mnemonic ch: create header
nnoremap <silent> ch :call CreateHeaderLine('ch' ,'.')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> cH :call CreateHeaderLine('cH', '-')<cr>

function! CreateHeaderLine(mapping, address)
  let c = nr2char(getchar())
  exe 't ' . a:address
  exe "norm! v$r" . c
  silent! call repeat#set(a:mapping . c)
endfunction
```